# Why do I get an error installing Ruby 1.9.3 using rvm on ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ruby, gcc, ubuntu, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I have no Rubies install on the system through `rvm`:

```
~ % rvm list
rvm rubies
```

I have 1.8.7 installed on the system:

```
~ % which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
~ % ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
```

While trying to install 1.9.3 using RVM I got the following errors:

```
% rvm install 1.9.3
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure
 --prefix=/home/omni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc  --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-libyaml-dir=/home/omni/.rvm/usr ', please read /home/omni/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

configure.log shows:

```
[2012-01-13 21:09:17]  ./configure
--prefix=/home/omni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc  --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-libyaml-dir=/home/omni/.rvm/usr  
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir 

checking build system type...
i686-pc-linux-gnu 

checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu

checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu 

checking whether the C compiler works... no 

configure: error: in
`/home/omni/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0': configure: error: C compiler
cannot create executables See `config.log' for more details
```

I tried running with `--with-gcc=clang` flag:

```
~ % rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang

ERROR: Error running '
./configure --prefix=/home/omni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0
--enable-shared --disable-install-doc  --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-gcc=clang --with-libyaml-dir=/home/omni/.rvm/usr ', please read /home/omni/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log ERROR: There has
been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

My gcc version is:

```
~ % gcc -v 

Using built-in specs. 

COLLECT_GCC=gcc 

COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper


Target: i686-linux-gnu 

Configured with: ../src/configure -v
--with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu 

Thread model: posix 

gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)
```

I've been at it for a long time and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following the directions given by `rvm dependencies`?

Comment: I slept on this issue and let my computer sleep as well (restart). This morning I was able to install ruby without a problem. Restart rarely fixes issues like these but in this case it did and I am really not keen on digging the issue deeper. thanks for help.